# FastAPI Return the number of deleted records

Tags: python, fastapi

In FastAPI I want to return the number of deleted rows.

I'm trying the following code but doesn't' return the number.

```
@app.delete("/remove/{id}", status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
def remove(id, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    effected_rows = db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id == id).delete()
    if effected_rows == 0:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    else:
        db.commit()
    return {
        "detail": effected_rows
    }
```

I want a similar thing for update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using SQLAlchemy. I'm also assuming that `models.Blog.id` is your primary key.

You can omit `delete()` part and do it later. Also, you can use `get(identifier)` to get the blog from DB. And since you will get 404 when the blog doesn't exist or 200 (or whatever) if the blog exists, you can omit the `return` part also, leaving you with this:

```py
blog = db.query(models.Blog).get(id)

if blog is None:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
else:
    db.delete(blog)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy than will use one query or wo queries, an select and than a delete  ? What if I want to know how many were deleted ?

Comment: Two queries will be executed at most: one select and one delete. I'm not sure what do you mean by the second question - you will have always one blog deleted (if it's in the DB) or zero (when it's not in the DB). That is of course if `models.Blog.id` is your primary key.